# How to execute another observable based on array from result returned from another one

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a quite simple situation but i got stuck. I have function `customGalleriesHttpService.list()` which returns observable with array of items. Lets assume:

```
[
{id:1,
... other stuff
},
{id:2,
... other stuff
}
]
```

Now I want to take each element from this array and make an extra http request `customGalleriesHttpService.images(data.id)` which returns observable with array of images for particular elemend based on his id. What i achived so far.

```
    this.customGalleriesHttpService.list().pipe(
      concatMap((data) => data),
      mergeMap((data) => this.customGalleriesHttpService.images(data.id)),
    ).subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

it is working but there is on more thing. It gives me output like this:

Array[6],
Array[6]

what i want to achive is to group this and return
[Array[6], Array[6]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `toArray()` operator before subscribe should work

```
this.customGalleriesHttpService.list().pipe(
  concatMap((data) => data),
  mergeMap((data) => this.customGalleriesHttpService.images(data.id)),
  toArray(), 
).subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. 
Big thanks! You saved my day! :)